# Get result data from pentaho data integration metadata injection

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

In pentaho data integration I am using metadata injection within a stream of a transformation. How can I get the result of the metadata injection back to my stream in order to continue transforming the data outside of the metadata injection. Copy rows to result does not seem to be working here like it does with a transformation within a transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself. In the Options tab you can select the step within the template to read the data from and below you can set the fields.

[metadata injection options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYTE0.png)